# "no data was received from host" Nagios Alarm only on Windows service checks

Tags: nagios, windows

I've got a standard Nagios install monitoring 524 hosts and 912 service checks.  I'm seeing a strange problem as far as it relates to monitoring if a service is running on windows server.  It seems like daily the service check will report "no data was received from host".

I don't want to instantly assume it's a network issue because all the other checks related to that host stay green the entire time.  The issue resolves itself within 3 minutes as well.

All the servers that share this issue are VM's located but not all windows vm's have the same issue.  There isn't much in common with the problem other than it being sqlserver.exe for a large number of them but it cna be other services such as sharepoint or WSUS.  I have other windows servers with this same style check but different exe files and I don't see the same problem.

I'm not sure what I should be searching for to help find the answer so I thought I would ask here.